# What does "Green address verification" mean in the context of transaction validation?

Tags: electrum, transaction-verification, terminology, zero-confirmation, green-address

I am only new to Bitcoin and I would like to know what a "Green address verification" is. I have an Electrum wallet ver 3.3.6 and I think the term is being used in the context of faster transactions but I am not sure. Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context where you saw this phrase?

Comment: It is in the wallet menu under preferences

Answer (score 1):

It is a way to validate a transaction without the need to wait for the blockchain confirmation, basically peoples will declare that they trust an adress and so people trusting them can directly transact with this new adress.

More infos and similar question here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/1731/95422